# Redux store states conditional initialization with localStorage during testing - React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-testing-library

I am using React Testing Library to test some features of my website and I am facing issues with the initialization of the Redux store while running tests. The following is the initialState:

```
const initialState = {
      isAuth: false,
      loading: localStorage.getItem("authToken") ? true : false,
      error: false,
      user: {
           username: "",
      },
 };
```

I have set up the tests with the following code to wrap everything around the Provider:

```
import { FC, ReactElement } from "react";
import { render, RenderOptions } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../store/store";

const AllTheProviders: FC = ({ children }) => {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
};

const customRender = (
  ui: ReactElement,
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, "wrapper">
) => render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });

export * from "@testing-library/react";
export { customRender as render };
```

Then, in the actual test I use `beforeAll(() => window.localStorage.setItem("authToken", "mockToken")` to set the token in localStorage. Based on the value of the `loading` state the Login component should be rendered on my website, but I'm always getting *false* as the value of loading.

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "../utils/test-utils";
import App from "../App";

beforeAll(() => window.localStorage.setItem("authToken", "MockAuthToken"));

test("Login page not rendered if a valid auth token is present", async () => {
  render(<App />);
  
  //this is to check that the Login component is not rendered
  await waitFor(() => expect(screen.queryByText("Sign in")).toBeNull());

  await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByRole("navigation")).toBeDefined(), {
    timeout: 5000,
  });
});
```

Is this happening because the Redux store is created before the *setItem* function execution during the tests? While in the browser the token is already there when I enter the website and so the intended behavior is not resembled by the test.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct.  We have an open issue asking us to add a "lazy initialization function" overload for `initialState` in `createSlice`:

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1024

I was actually working on trying to implement this last night and have a PR up, but there's some concerns about changes in the semantics of behavior:

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/1662

I'll look at this some more tonight and see what we can come up with.